# Why is my avrokey datum saying it is a Generic Record When I explicitly wrote the data as AvroKey<SpecificRecord>?

Tags: java, hadoop, avro

I am feeding the avro output from one hadoop job into another hadoop job. The first job just runs a mapper with the following setup. If it is of any use, my avsc file defines a compound object like this:

```
[
{
"type": "record",
"name": "MySubRecord",
"namespace": "blah",
"fields": [
    {"name": "foobar", "type": ["null","string"], "default":null},
    {"name": "bar","type": ["null","string"], "default":null},
    {"name": "foo","type": ["null","string"], "default":null},
]
},{
"type": "record",
"name": "MyRecord",
"namespace" : "blah",
"fields" : [
       {"name": "ID", "type":["null", "string"], "default":null},
       {"name": "secondID", "type":["null", "string"], "default":null},
       {"name": "subRecordA", "type":["null","blah.MySubRecord"], "default":null},
       {"name": "subRecordB", "type":["null","blah.MySubRecord"], "default":null},
       {"name": "subRecordC", "type":["null","blah.MySubRecord"], "default":null},
       {"name": "subRecordD", "type":["null","blah.MySubRecord"], "default":null},
       {"name": "subRecordE", "type":["null","blah.MySubRecord"], "default":null},
       {"name": "subRecordF", "type":["null","blah.MySubRecord"], "default":null},
       {"name": "subRecordG", "type":["null","blah.MySubRecord"], "default":null},
       {"name": "subRecordH", "type":["null","blah.MySubRecord"], "default":null}
]
}
]
```

while my mapper class signature looks like this:

```
public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, AvroKey<MyRecord>, NullWritable>
```

with a setup method like this:

```
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);
        keyOut = new AvroKey<>();}
```

the mapper code looks like this

```
protected void map(LongWritable keyIn, Text valueIn, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        MyRecord record;
        record = getMyRecordFunction();
        keyOut.datum(record);
        context.write(keyOut, NullWritable.get());

    }
```

My logic in my first job looks good because when I use the command line avro-tools jar to print my output to json, it looks as I would expect it to.

My problem occurs when I run my second job. The mapper for my second job has the following setup:

```
public static class MySecondJobMapper extends Mapper<AvroKey<MyRecord>, NullWritable, IntWritable, DoubleWritable>
```

and my issue occurs at the very beginning of the map method in my second job. My map method looks like this:

```
protected void map(AvroKey<MyRecord> key, NullWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        MyRecord myRecord = key.datum();
##### some other logic
```

Everytime I run the second job, I get the following error:

```
    16/07/28 18:24:38 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1682958846_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to MyRecord
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to MyRecord
    at your.class.path$StatsCalculatorMapper.map(YourSecondJob.java:150)
    at your.class.path$StatsCalculatorMapper.map(YourSecondJob.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was stemming from the fact that I was testing in a local, pseudo-distributed environment and the correct avro version specified in my pom.xml was not being pulled in. Instead, an older version of avro with the [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1351) was being pulled in without me realizing it. Once I ran the same program on EMR, it worked just fine because the correct version of avro was being used.